# Temperature Sensor (DS18B20) doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, gpio, raspbian-jessie, ds18b20

I am having trouble getting to run my temperature sensor. 
If I execute the following script to check if the PIN 7 gives me an output, it returns 1 (as it ought to).

```
import re, os, urllib2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPIO.setwarnings(True)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)

    print GPIO.input(7)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Furthermore I am VERY sure, that the setup of my temperature sensor is correct, you can see an image of it here:

[image]

As it goes into the GPIO ports, the wires are arranged like this:
[image]

For all of this I was using a Rasperry Pi 3 Model B V1.2. 
My kernel Version is 4.4.50-v7+
As Operating System I am using Raspbian 8 (jessie)

Could it be a hardware, or a software error? I also changed up all the files as you see it in various tutorials (see comments) but still it doesn't show up in the w1/devices folder. Please help me, I have no idea what I could have done wrong. If you need further information feel free to ask.

Comment: I used this tutorial: https://www.golem.de/news/mitmachprojekt-temperatur-messen-und-senden-mit-dem-raspberry-pi-1604-120188.html

Comment: I watched the video on the tutorial website you mentioned. Something is missing on the video of your reference tutorial(Since I don't know German I watched the video). The following link will be helpful for you to configure DS18B20. https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-temperature-sensor/ . Also adafruit lesson written by Dr. Simon Monk is also very helpful for your project(following link). https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HkM_BeqkJxSi13aExqT1AwZVU/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: thank you very much! Hope these links help. You can also watch another tutorial if you want, I'm sure they just copied it from an english source

Comment: I think problem is with configuration of your 1-wire protocol which is not mentioned in the tutorial you referred. To know more about 1-wire protocol configuration for ds18b20 read https://pinout.xyz/pinout/1_wire this one too.

Comment: Oh yeah I will! After a little debugging I'll tell you wether or not it helped

Comment: Did you enable your dtoverlay for 1-wire protocol at `/boot/config.txt`. Your code doesn't seem to be correct, you don't get the reading directly from a GPIO pin. 1-wire protocol return the data in a form as a file, in fact if everything setup correctly, you can get the reading by running command `cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/xx-xxxxxxxxxx/w1-slave` without running a python script. You can take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2017/04/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-data-logger/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did I'll check it

Comment: Then what do you see if you run `cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/xx-xxxxxxxxxx/w1-slave`? where `xx-xxxxxxxxxx` is the unique serial number of the ds18b20.

Comment: Yes I tried it. Still no result, I think I made a mistake while soldering the wires? Either I destroyed the sensor due to the current and high temperatures, or I arrenged the wires and the resistor in a wrong way. Guess I'll try to resolder everything and try it again. At least my Pi is still working :P But I really checked all what I could have don wrong in configuration and found absoulutely nothing. So.. with me luck *fingers crossed*

Comment: Hey just wanted to give you all a quick uodate (maybe someone cares). Since I am using a breadboard everything works just fine so I think I connected the wires in a wrong way